# TextView setText & shared preferences manager

Tags: java, android, textview, sharedpreferences

I want to ask something. I use `SharedPreferences` to save users data but can I show the users data to the `TextView` from database & API response without shared preference manager ?

Comment: yes you can do that , try using firebase realtime database

Comment: Owh but can i use mysql database ?

Comment: yes you can you need to create an API to fetch and update the data in mysql

Comment: Hmm okay i'll try, thankyou 

Comment: @deHaar `ContentProvider` is not really the use case . Its only used when you need to share data among applications, its also mentioned in Doc see line `Decide if you need a content provider.`  . A simple Sqlite DB is enough .

Comment: Hmm guys.. Can i put the API response as TextView ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, to answer the question - yes, yes you can.
However, I have a couple of recommendations.

I wouldn't use *SharedPreferences* to store the userData. *SharedPreferences* are used to store simple, unstructured values. Here's what the [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage#pref) say:

> If you don't need to store a lot of data and it doesn't require structure, you should use SharedPreferences. The SharedPreferences APIs allow you to read and write persistent key-value pairs of primitive data types: booleans, floats, ints, longs, and strings...

As one of the comments suggests, I would look at a *database* for that. If you want the database to be local (stored on the phone), I'd suggest *SQLite* - have a look at the [*Room library*](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/). If you want the database to be stored on a server, then [Firebase Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/) is your easiest solution.

Comment: Wow thank you very much @Mitch, thank you also for your suggestions, and now i pretty understand what SharedPreferences used for

Comment: No worries buddy